# How do I connect to the internet (newly reformatted laptop)?

Tags: laptop, wireless-networking, wireless-router

After my laptop was reformatted(Win7) it could no longer connect to wireless. Do I need to setup anything?

When I use the ipconfig command in cmd this shows:

> Ethernet adapter local area
>   connection: Media State: ....Media
>   disconnected
>
> Tunnel adapter isatap Media State:
>   ....Media disconnected

(and more tunnel adapter ..media disconnected stuff)

I tried to connect with internet through a cable but it still shows media disconnected. I cannot connect to the net at all.

Comment: are drivers installed?
do you even see wireless connection?
a bit vague question, needs more details

Comment: no I don't see wireless connection. Are drivers not installed by default? Do I need internet to install drivers? (that would be a problem)

Comment: Visit the manufacturer's website from the connection your using to visit this site, download the drivers to a USB key and then install it on the laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the model.

Cick the `Start Orb`.

Right click `Computer`.

Click `Manage`.

Expand `Device Manager` and look for any yellow triangles.

If you do not see any, it is most likely a software issue, you simply need to scan and connect to the Wireless network. If however you do see a yellow triangle, this means that the wireless card has not been correctly installed. You will need to go to the manufacturer (or your machine or wireless card) and download the correct drivers.

Comment: Other Devices -> Multimedia Audio Controller, Network Controller and Video Controller all have yellow triangles. :(

Comment: You can also try loading drivers off your original discs if you have them.  Most packaged laptops will come with manufacturer CDs that have the drivers backed up.  They may not be the LATEST but they should allow you to get online to get updates.

Comment: @Dian - That means you have not installed video (your graphics performance will be much less than they should be capable of), audio (could just be audio over video e.g. if you have a HDMI socket - this will be installed automatically with graphics drivers) and the network controller will probably be the wireless network card. Look at manufacturers websites for the latest updates for drivers.

Comment: @JNK I do not have manufacturer CD. :( what else can I do?

Comment: @Wil I cannot connect to the internet at all (even with cables).

Comment: @Dian - Make a list of the model # and make of all the hardware with a triangle, get a flash drive, go to a working computer, download it all, and load it on your pc with the flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run Windows Update and check for available drivers?

edit: in case you have a wired connection

Comment: I do not have internet connection at all.